# What is the meaning of this operation

Tags: c, expression, bitwise-and, logical-or, logical-and

So we got this piece of code on a test and I had zero idea what is the meaning and how it works.
`unsigned int a = 1, b = 2, c;`
and then `c = a&b || a&&b;`

The question was: What is the value of `c`. Answer was 1.

Can somebody explain what is happening in initialization of `c`?

Comment: What did your research in your C beginner's book reveal? Why did it not help you? (You might like to read some of the [help] to learn how this site works. It is not a forum.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assignment statement

```
c = a&b || a&&b;
```

may be rewritten for clarity the followinmg way

```
c = ( a&b ) || ( a&&b );
```

`a & b` is the bitwise AND operation.  As `a` is equal to `1` and `b` is equal to `2` then the result of the operation is equal to `0` (I am using only 8 bits in the number representations for simplicity)

```
00000001
&
00000010
========
00000000
```

From the C Standard (6.5.10 Bitwise AND operator)

> 4 The result of the binary & operator is the bitwise AND of the
> operands (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only if each
> of the corresponding bits in the converted operands is set).

In this expression `a && b` there is the logical AND operation. It is equal to `1` when the both operands are unequal to `0`. As `a` and `b` are unequal to `0` then the result of the operation is `1`.

From the C Standard (6.5.13 Logical AND operator)

> 3 The && operator shall yield 1 if both of its operands compare
> unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.

So you have

```
c = 0 || 1;
```

where the logical OR operation is used. It yields `1` if at least one operand is not equal to `0`.

From the C Standard (6.5.14 Logical OR operator)

> 3 The || operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare
> unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.

So the variable `c` will be assigned with the value `1`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation :) Now I finally get it.

Comment: But you did not write what actually it does. When `c` will be `1` or  `0` (ie what sense does it have)

Answer (score 1):

The `unsigned int` variables `a` and `b` hold some bit-pattern that represent 1 and 2. It won't be this, but for the sake of the description, let's say

```
  a = 0b0001
  b = 0b0010
```

That would be the numbers 1 and 2 in a 4-bit integer.

The `&` operator does bit-wise and, so bit by bit you evaluate `(0,0)->0`, `(0,1)->0`, `(1,0)->0` and `(1,1)`. So, for the two integers above

```
    a = 0b0001
    b = 0b0010
  a&b = 0b0000
```

We see that `a&b` is zero, since they do not have any overlapping 1-bits.

The operator `&&` does a logical and, which means that the result is 1 if both arguments are non-zero and zero otherwise. So `a && b = 1` because neither `a` and `b` are zero.

```
     a = 0b0001
     b = 0b0010
  a&&b = 0b0001
```

The `||` operator is logical or; it gives you 1 if any of the arguments are non-zero and only zero if both arguments are zero. So, since

```
  a&b = 0b0000
 a&&b = 0b0001
```

where `a&&b` is non-zero, you get `c = (a&b) || (a&&b) = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain it from another point of view.

`a&b` will give non zero only if both have at least one bit set at the same position

`a&&b` will give `1` only if both are not zero

`a&b || a&&b` will give be one only if both are not zero and have at least one bit set at the same position.

It can be reduced to:

`int c = a&&b;`